# WrapPanel and first line

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have items wrapped in wrap panel. 
I want to move first line of items down by some offset.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Margin property of your WrapPanel...

Margin="0, 5, 0 ,0" (Left, Top, Right, Bottom)

HTH

Comment: To be more precise, I need to set top Padding

Comment: You can set the Margin of the First element, which translates to Padding seen from the WrapPanel...